# Nodemailer does not send emails in aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, sendmail, nodemailer

I have hosted my node js app on amazon web service, with the elastic beanstalk service. I'm sending emails with nodemailer and it worked fine locally but after I hosted the app in aws so it just stopped sending emails. I've tried to solve the problem but it did not work, and I have also opened port 465 but with no results.

So how to solve the problem, I've tried using aws ses but it did not work.

THis is the error I'm getting:

```
_http_outgoing.js:561
 throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');

 Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
 at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
Dec 14 19:28:14 ip-172-31-18-123 web: at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:561:11)
 at ServerResponse.header (/var/app/current/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
 at ServerResponse.send (/var/app/current/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
 at ServerResponse.json (/var/app/current/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
 at /var/app/current/controllers/user_api.js:116:32
 at /var/app/current/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js:230:21
 at /var/app/current/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-transport/index.js:282:36
 at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (/var/app/current/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1536:20)
 at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:540:26) {
 code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
 web: }
```

Here is my code

```
const transport = nodeMailer.createTransport({
  
  service: "gmail",
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.DORENT_GMAIL,
    pass: process.env.DORENT_GMAIL_PASSWORD,
  },
});

 const mailOption = {
      from: process.env.DORENT_GMAIL,
      to: user.userMail,
      subject: "Verifyera mailaddress",
      html: `Please click this link to verify your link: <a href=${url}>${url}</a>`,
    };

    // console.log(mailOption);
    // console.log(transport);
    transport.sendMail(mailOption, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: "error", message: err.message });
      } else {
        console.log("Mail has been sent");
      }
    });
```

Comment: Try looking at the error logs. Are you sure the environment variables were loaded correctly? Did you install nodemailer? Is there an authentication error?

Comment: the environment variables are loaded correctly

Comment: It doesn't look like it's an error with NodeMailer. Can you list all your files?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly make sure you've **enabled less secure apps** on your Gmail account: [How to enable less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

Then make sure you've **enabled multifactor**: [How to enable multifactor on your Gmail](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839)

You'll then want to generate an **app password** to use when logging in with nodemailer. You can do it following this guide: [Generate app password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)

Then I had to use [nodemailer-smpt-transport](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/) and the [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) packages to make this work on Firebase cloud functions.

I'd imagine it might work for AWS:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});

var transport = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
   service: "gmail",
   host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
   port: 465,
   secure: true,
   auth: {
      user: process.env.DORENT_GMAIL,
      pass: GMAIL_APP_PASSWORD,
   },
}));

cors(req, res, () => {
    const mailOption = {
       from: process.env.DORENT_GMAIL,
       to: user.userMail,
       subject: "Verifyera mailaddress",
       html: `Please click this link to verify your link:`,
    };
    transport.sendMail(mailOption, (err) => {
       if (err) {
           return res.status(500).json({ error: "error", message: err.message });
       } else {
           console.log("Mail has been sent");
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: I don't think you're using CORS quite right. Also, notice that the OP tried sending emails locally successfully, meaning it may not be something to configure on Gmail.